# Count the frequency that a bunch of values occurs in a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, count, frequency

pretty new to python and pandas, i have a 15000 values in a column of my dataframe like this.

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 0.05964 |
| 19 | 0.00325 |
| 31 | 0.0225 |
| 12 | 0.03325 |
| 14 | 0.00525 |

I want to get in output a result like this :

```
0.00 to 0.01 = 55 values, 
0.01 to 0.02 = 365 values, 
0.02 to 0.03 = 5464 values etc... from 0.00 to 1.00
```

Im a bit lost with groupby or count.values etc...

thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, use `pd.cut`:

```
out = df.groupby(pd.cut(df['col2'], np.linspace(0, 1, 101)))['col1'].sum()
print(out)

# Output
col2
(0.0, 0.01]     33
(0.01, 0.02]     0
(0.02, 0.03]    31
(0.03, 0.04]    12
(0.04, 0.05]     0
                ..
(0.95, 0.96]     0
(0.96, 0.97]     0
(0.97, 0.98]     0
(0.98, 0.99]     0
(0.99, 1.0]      0
Name: col1, Length: 100, dtype: int64
```